# How to store 2 Strings and an dependent array/vector in JAVA?

Tags: java

I´m currently trying to save some dependent Information from two different SQL statements in a single structure or datatype.
So this is the situation:

1. First SQL request gets all objects --> result is always 2 strings (`name` & `status`)
2. Depending on `status` another SQL request is fired to get the error message of the objects which have a certain value in `status`  --> result is varying number of strings (`msg`) but at least one
3. Return the list of objects with their name, status and any error message

Here is the (modifyed and shortened) code:

```
    Vector<String> errMsgList = new Vector<String>();

    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rslt = null;
    ResultSet errors = null;

    try
    {
        conn = DBTransaction.begin();

        String sql = " ";//SQL statement to get all objects

        rslt = DBSQLUtil.executeQuery(sql.toString(), conn);
        while (rslt.next())
        {
            String objectName = rslt.getString(1);
            String status = rslt.getString(2);

            if (status.equals("INVALID")){  


                String errorSql = " "; //SQL statement to get errorMessage of current object

                errors = DBSQLUtil.executeQuery(errorSql.toString(), conn);

                while(errors.next()){
                    errMsgList.add(errors.getString(1));
                }                   
            }
            String[] entry = { objectName, status };
        }
        return;//return structure with name, status and messages of the object
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        DBSQLUtil.closeResultSet(rslt);
        DBTransaction.rollback(conn);
    }
```

Due to the fact that the amount of error messages varies, the messages are added to a `Vector<String>`. The `name` and `status` of the single objects are stored in a `String[]` structure. How can I bring together the name and  status of the object with the belonging optional list of error messages?

Comment: I would suggest you should work through Object/Class part of a java-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a bean class:

```
Class Struct{
    private String name;
    private String status;
    private Vector<String> errMsgList;
    public Struct(String name, String status, Vector<String> errMsgList){
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status
        this.errMsgList= errMsgList
    }
}
```

And then when you get datas from database:

```
Vector<Struct> structs = new Vector<>();
while(errors.next()){
    errMsgList.add(errors.getString(1));
}
Struct struct = new Struct(objectName, status, errMsgList);
structs.add(struct);
.
.
.

return structs;
```

:D

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to create a bean class with below properties and return array of bean class

```
public class StatusDTO {
   private String objectName;
   private String status;
   private Vector<String> errorMsgList = new Vector<String>();

   getters.....
   setters.....
}
```

add all properties to the pojo class and return array of xyx[]. I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Furthermore, instead of suggesting `Vector` and arrays, you should take the modern approach of using `List` and `ArrayList` for these kinds of task.

Comment: @RolandIllig I have just provided the solution in high level for specific problem of setting the values to a bean and how to return the value to calling method. Moreover in john's question, its high level code snippet not the complete source code.